# Netplan overwrite previous config?

Tags: ubuntu, netplan

I have a couple netplan config files, one that configures the machine statically

```
# /etc/netplan/02-static-config.yaml
network:
    ethernets:
        enp0s3:
            addresses:
              - {my static IP}
            gateway4: {my gateway}
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                  - { some }
                  - { DNS servers }
            dhcp4: false
    version: 2
```

and one that very simply configures it to use DHCP

```
# /etc/netplan/03-dhcp-config.yaml
network:
    ethernets:
        enp0s3:
            dhcp4: true
            addresses: []
    version: 2
```

I then wrote a couple shell scripts that renames the DHCP script to either `01` (if I wanted statics) or `03` (if I wanted DHCP), then called `netplan generate` and `netplan apply`.

Unfortunately, although [the docs](https://netplan.io/reference) seem to imply that the `addresses` mapping from `03-dhcp-config.yaml` should override `02-static-config.yaml`:

> Lexicographically later files (regardless of in which directory they are) amend (new mapping keys) or **override (same mapping keys) previous ones.** *ed: emphasis mine*.

what I'm actually seeing is that both addresses bind to the same interface.

```
username@machine:~$ ip address show enp0s3
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:6d:2c:d6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet {my static IP} brd {a bridge} scope global enp0s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet {a DHCP address} brd {and associate bridge} scope global secondary dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 691170sec preferred_lft 691170sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe6d:2cd6/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

How can I make `03-dhcp-config.yaml` override `02-static-config.yaml`? Or alternatively: how can I disable `02-static-config.yaml` quickly and easily?

Comment: Note: this is crossposted from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1355643/netplan-overwrite-previous-config) not sure if this is more in-line with superuser or server fault!

Comment: It is valid for an interface to have both static and DHCP assigned addresses. But the old Debian interfaces file had no way to represent this configuration, so most Debian/Ubuntu users never configured this, or even knew it was possible.

Comment: @MichaelHampton right, and that's cool info, but isn't the way I'm trying to configure my system! I would think that specifying `addresses: []` in the DHCP config would override the `addresses: [{my static IP}]` line in the static config, but it's not.

Comment: Aha, I see what you're saying. It could possibly be a bug. Of course, netplan is pretty much pointless garbage anyway, so you might just want to get rid of it and write the systemd-networkd configs yourself.